# HTML Page of GWT Project

Tags: html, gwt, gxt, uibinder, gwt2

In the Project of GWT/GXT.

in project.html.

I added the favicon and change the color of the body and also put an image .

But when i run the web project. i cant see the the change in body color, favicon and the Image.

My web Projects starts from login page which is in a center of on the RootPanel.

I want add a Image and Fevicon in HTML

In my test page test.html i can display favicon and image.

gwt project.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="fevicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gxt/css/gxt-all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />
</head>
<body style="background-color:d8d8d8;>
    <img class="normal" src="main.png" width="700" height="80" />
    <script language='javascript' src='project/project.nocache.js'></script>

    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
</body>
</html

 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Manolo suggest check working folder. i.e. war/modulename and also clear cache of browser. because if browser already have cache of it so sometime changes does not reflect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are modifying a page which is not being copied to the working folder of your app 
when running in web mode.

Sometimes eclipse does not update files from sources to working dir.

Try to find the file `test.html` in other folders and compare their sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In your src/main/webapp changes not seen at a moment. Refresh project and restart development mode. If any changes recompile your project(Last choice).